# unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

whenever i try this codes it gives an error "unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts" i already test this on my localhost and its a success but when i try this code on hosting providers it just wont work!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace testingform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Connection Variables;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string connString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connString = @"SERVER= testwebsite.com;PORT=3306;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword;";

            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = connString;
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: try changing the server to IP address.

Comment: some hosting providers requre security configuration (allow connections from specific ip) for database.